# Problem while constructing networkx graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have the following `data` in dataframe format

```
  a       b
-510    -350
-300    -120
-350    -170
-170     30
 30      210
-120     30
-690    -510
```

Using this data I am trying to construct `networkx` graph using python and so far written following codes

```
import networkx as nx

G1 = nx.DiGraph()
G1.add_edges_from(data)
data_1= nx.spring_layout(G1)

fig1=plt.figure(figsize=(5,2),dpi=300)
nx.draw(G1, data_1, node_size=1000, with_labels=True, node_color='y',vertex_label_size=100)
```

But getting following error `Edge tuple start must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple` which is basically from adding edges. I tried some google search could not find any suitable answer to solve this. Could you please help me with this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help?  :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967714/networkx-with-errors-from-adding-nodes-and-edges

Answer (score 1):

To  build a graph from a pandas dataframe, you have `nx.from_pandas_edgelist`:

```
G1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='a', target='b', create_using=nx.DiGraph)
pos= nx.spring_layout(G1)

fig1=plt.figure(figsize=(5,2),dpi=300)
nx.draw(G1, pos, node_size=100, with_labels=True, node_color='y')
```

[image]